# Ошибка в QT - Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: python, qt

Вылезла ошибка. Версию переустановил, но все равно не работает;

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from test import Ui_Dialog

#Create app
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#init
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

#Main Loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

при запуске приложения в каталоге приложения должно лежать .\platforms\qwindows.dll